# Comparing date/time values in microsoft access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am having some trouble comparing date/time values in Microsoft Access.

I am currently using the query below to get all the absence records for the day. I have no issues when it is a plain date value but records with time included cannot be retrieved with the query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE [Start Date/Time] <= Date() AND [End Date/Time] >= Date()
```

I have a table used to store absence records of the following form.

```
Name: Text
Start Date/Time: Date/Time
End Date/Time: Date/Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE Fix([Start Date/Time]) <= Date() AND Fix([End Date/Time]) >= Date()
```

to remove the time part, or:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DateDiff("d", [Start Date/Time], Date()) >= 0 AND DateDiff("d", [End Date/Time], Date()) <= 0
```

to ignore the time part.